# Server Error in the application '/

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I convert the project from 4.0 to 4.5 framework, after convertion every thing is working fine in VS2013 and i checked it by deploying it in my local IIS. every thing is working fine. but when i host it in Client server, i am getting "***The base class includes the field 'HTML1', but its type (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlElement) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl.)*** " in masterpage.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recompile the code using the .net 4.5 runtime.
And when doing this, you need to change the *.designer.cs file reference from:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl html;
```

To:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlElement html.
```